# Invalid handle error when connecting to COM port higher than 10 on Windows 7

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-7, serial-port

I have developed a simple serial port application that works fine with COM ports lower than 10 (COM9, COM8, ...  COM1). But when my device is attached on a port higher than 10, such as COM11, it doesn't connect and I get an INVALID_HANDLE. My code is:

```
comport = CreateFileA(comPortName.toAscii(), GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE,
                      FILE_SHARE_READ|FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);

if(comport == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    //Write exception code here
    connectionStatus = CONNECTION_STATUS_DISCONNECTED;
}
```

What's wrong with my code? Is there any solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To reach the COM Ports >= 10 you can use the driver's symbolic link. For example, for COM10 it is `\\\\.\\COM10`.

Just try:

```
comport = CreateFileA("\\\\.\\COM10", GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE,
                  FILE_SHARE_READ|FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);

if(comport == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    // Write exception code here
    connectionStatus = CONNECTION_STATUS_DISCONNECTED;
}
```

Of course, this also works for COM ports < 10.

Comment: thanks, it works. But can you explain why we need this for COM ports >=10 ?

Comment: This is a good question. The aliases `COMx` seems to be from the old days. In this time it was not very common to have more than 4 COM ports. And COM Ports where not implemented in a plug and play way. Fact is, this mechanism will not work for more than 1 digit in the port name. Maybe they still exists for compatibility. By the way the `\\.\xxx` trick gives access to a lot of device drivers which are not available over simple aliases like COM1-9 are.

Answer (score 2):

You need to prepend "\\.\" to the COM port name, so it should be something like:

```
  CreateFileA("\\\\.\\COM10", ... )
```

Source: *[HOWTO: Specify Serial Ports Larger than COM9](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/115831)*