# How come GetDefaultCommConfig fails on windows 10

Tags: c++, winapi, serial-port

I use the following code to verify that a serial port name is valid on the computer:

```
typedef std::pair<StrAsc const, bool> port_pair_type;
typedef std::list<port_pair_type> port_pairs_type;
port_pairs_type pairs;
StrBin config_buffer;
 config_buffer.fill(0,sizeof(COMMCONFIG));
while(!pairs.empty())
{
   port_pair_type pair(pairs.front());
   pairs.pop_front();
   if(!pair.second)
   {
      // we need to get the default configuration for the port.  This may
      // require some fudging on the buffer size.  That is why two calls
      // are being made.
      uint4 config_size = config_buffer.length();
      StrUni temp(pair.first);
      COMMCONFIG *config(reinterpret_cast<COMMCONFIG *>(config_buffer.getContents_writable()));
      config->dwSize = sizeof(COMMCONFIG);
      rcd = GetDefaultCommConfigW(
         temp.c_str(), config, &config_size);
      if(!rcd && config_buffer.length() < config_size)
      {
         config_buffer.fill(0, config_size);
         config = reinterpret_cast<COMMCONFIG *>(config_buffer.getContents_writable());
         config->dwSize = sizeof(COMMCONFIG);
         rcd = GetDefaultCommConfigW(
            temp.c_str(),
            reinterpret_cast<COMMCONFIG *>(config_buffer.getContents_writable()),
                 &config_size);
      }

      // if the call succeeded, we can go ahead and look at the
      // configuration structure.
      if(rcd)
      {
         COMMCONFIG const *config = reinterpret_cast<COMMCONFIG const *>(
         config_buffer.getContents());
         if(config->dwProviderSubType == PST_RS232)
            port_names.push_back(pair.first);
      }
      else
      {
         OsException error("GetDefaultCommConfig Failed");
         trace("\"%s\"", error.what());
      }
   }
   else
      port_names.push_back(pair.first);
}
```

On windows 10, when trying to confirm a serial port that uses usbser.sys, the call to GetDefaultCommConfig() is failing and the error code returned by GetLastError() is 87 (invalid parameter).  As I am aware, the usbser.sys driver has been rewritten on windows 10 and I suspect that this is a problem with that driver.  Does anyone else have an idea of what might be going wrong?

Comment: Every use of `reinterpret_cast` raises a red flag. Double check to make sure the `COMMCONFIG` data you are sending it actually _valid_. Reduce your code to something where you explicitly initialize an anstance of  `COMMCONFIG` with values _known_ to work.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious COMMCONFIG is a variable length structure that, depending upon the driver, must be enlarged to hold extra information.  I do this in the StrBin (binary buffer class) in order to manage this allocation.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious I would further point out that this code works for every other port type except those that use the usbser.sys driver.  It also works on older operating systems.

Comment: What is the set port number? Keep in mind that port descriptors with something like "\\\\.\\COM20" will not work. Refer also to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13191777/invalid-handle-error-when-connecting-to-com-port-higher-than-10-on-windows-7?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This had been a bug in `usbser.sys` and was fixed with the Windows 10 Update `KB3124262` from 27.01.2016.

The Microsoft employee explained:

> The COM port name in the HKLM\HARDWARE\DEVICEMAP\SERIALCOMM registry is not NULL terminated.

[Related discussion on MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3d759c8d-fb7e-4693-acf3-bb082f02fc1c/windows-10-getdefaultcommconfig-error-87-on-all-com-ports-handled-by-usbsersys?forum=wdk)

Because of Windows 10's update policies this issue should not appear in the future anymore.

Answer (score -1):

When you call GetDefaultCommConfigW the second time you probably need to `config->dwSize` to the new size the structure. Eg:

```
config->dwSize = config_size;
```

Comment: I just tried that and it seems to make no difference.  The documentation for GetDefaultCommConfig() states that the dwSize parameter should be set to sizeof(COMMCONFIG).

Comment: @JonTrauntvein Normally for structures that can change size the dwSize member is set to the actual size of the structure. Since you're reusing the buffer you may need to set it to the value of config_size on every call. You may also need to zero out the buffer before each call.

Comment: Look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363188(v=vs.85).aspx where it states for dwSize: "The size of the structure, in bytes. The caller must set this member to sizeof(COMMCONFIG)."  I have changed my code to initialise the structure each time before GetDefaultCommConfig is called but this doesn't appear to make any difference.

Comment: @JonTrauntvein Microsoft's documentation has numerous errors. According to the documentation your code should work.

Comment: I have tried to set dwSize to the allocated buffer size but, in my experience, this member value does not appear to make any difference.  I suspect that this is a driver implementation issue.