# Invalid parameter error using GetDefaultCommConfig

Tags: c++, string, windows

I came up with the same issue,in which I got a LPTSTR portname param as input from a function.I have to convert this into wstring,so that I can fetch the Port paramaters.

below is the code snippet in which am trying to copy lptstr to wstring.

```
         void C_PORT_MONITOR::SetPrinterComPortParam(LPTSTR   PortName)
          {
          #ifdef _UNICODE
          std::wstring          l_ComPortName;
          #else
          std::string               l_ComPortName;
          #endif
         DWORD dwSize,le = 0;
      dwSize = sizeof(COMMCONFIG);
     LPCOMMCONFIG lpCC = (LPCOMMCONFIG) new BYTE[dwSize];
     l_ComPortName = PortName;//mPortName;  
        if(l_ComPortName.length() <= 0 )
        return;
   bool SetFlag = false;
 //Get COMM port params called to get size of config. block
  int length = l_ComPortName.length();
  int iPos = l_ComPortName.find_first_of(':'); 
  int iChc = length- iPos; //remove the charactrers after :
  l_ComPortName = l_ComPortName.substr(0, (length- iChc)); //remove the characters from colon  //COM1
//Get COMM port params with defined size
   BOOL ret = GetDefaultCommConfig(l_ComPortName.c_str(), lpCC, &dwSize);  
_RPT1(_CRT_WARN, "C_PORT_MONITOR::SetPrinterComPortParam length=%x,iPos=%x,iChc=%x,l_ComPortName=%s",length, iPos, iChc, l_ComPortName);
if(!ret)
{
    le = GetLastError();
    _RPT1(_CRT_WARN ,"C_PORT_MONITOR::SetPrinterComPortParam LastError=%x",le);
}
```

I need to assign this portname to l_comportname. and I need to create a substring from this l_comportname as COM1 and I have to use this substring in getdafaultcommconfig()

Comment: So what's the error when you try this code (because it looks OK to me)?

Comment: getdafaultcommconfig() fails with lasterror 57(invalid parameter). So am suspecting on its first parameter. Aslo I should get l_Comportparam.c_str() as "com1" but instead am getting only "C"

Comment: @Christophe I agree to close the question, but I do not see how this is a duplicate of the question you linked. Here the questioner does not say that he has a runtime error.

Comment: Doesn't seem like the duplicate is correct at all to me. The OP doesn't get an error on conversion (in fact he doesn't seem to be doing a conversion at all).

Comment: @JanuSasi It wasn't clear at all from your original question that this was a run time error, I assumed you had a compiler error. Now this just looks like a bug in your code somewhere, probably not even in the code you posted. What's the value of `PortName` on entry to the function?

Comment: @JanuSasi Incidentally this code `int iPos = l_ComPortName.find_first_of(':'); 
  int iChc = length- iPos;
  l_ComPortName = l_ComPortName.substr(0, (length- iChc));` is more simply written as `int iPos = l_ComPortName.find_first_of(':'); l_ComPortName = l_ComPortName.substr(0, iPos);`

Comment: THE VALUSE FOR PORTNAME on entry is "COM3:,0000000001391AB0"

Comment: Please edit the question and the title because it's unclear what you ask and the title is misleading. If it's about converting strings, the dupe I referred to provided everything needed to convert (the question showed how to convert and the answer how to correctly use the arguments). If it's about compile time error, please show us for which line. If it's about weird results, tell us the expected result and the result that you have.

Comment: @Christophe The title reflects a misunderstanding the OP had about the bug, turns out it's a completely different issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is the second parameter not the first. Your debugging statement is bugged because it doesn't account for wide strings `%s` is for narrow strings only, you should use `%S` for a wide string.

Here's the real error

```
 dwSize = sizeof(COMMCONFIG);
 LPCOMMCONFIG lpCC = (LPCOMMCONFIG) new BYTE[dwSize];
 lpCC->dwSize = sizeof(COMMCONFIG); // this line is needed
```

You might need this as well (the documentation isn't very clear)

```
 lpCC->wVersion = 1;
```

It's very common in Windows programming that you have to initialize a struct with the size of the struct.

Ref: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/aa363188(v=vs.90)

Comment: +1 for your effort to understand and solve an unclear question and for providing a useful answer clarifying the right usage of a function. However it will help the community only if others can recognize similar issues based on a clear question title...

Comment: @Christophe Thanks, I've changed it to something more neutral.

Comment: @john.. Thanks for your help.Actually I suspected on type conversion,thats why I named the title like that. Anyway thanks for changing the topic. And as you said I tried to initialize lpCC->dwSize and   lpCC->wVersion .And also I changed the type specifier to %S,after changing the specifier I got"String too long or IO ERROR".I was not able to get the proper output. And still the getdafaultcommconfig() is failing with last error 57. Still am not sure whats wrong with the parameters in the function call.

Comment: @JanuSasi Unfortunately I'm not too familar with these functions, I'm just going by the documentation. So one feature of `GetDefaultCommConfig` is that you can't know in advance how much memory you need for the second parameter. If it's too small then the function fails but the ammount of space you do need is returned in the third parameter. So often you have to call it twice, the first time just find out how much space you really need, and the second time should work. Maybe that's happening to you.

Comment: @JanuSasi Also there' s a known bug in Windows 10, see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31482368/how-come-getdefaultcommconfig-fails-on-windows-10. That question also has some sample code for calling `GetDefaultCommConfig` include calling it twice like I explained above.

Comment: @JanuSasi Not sure why you are having trouble with `%S` is is the correct specifier for a wide string, see here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/format-specification-syntax-printf-and-wprintf-functions?view=vs-2017